# Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: abort(undefined) at Error in codepen mediapipe

Tags: javascript, codepen, mediapipe

I am trying to use codepen mdeiapipe pose detection files in my project but i am getting these below javascript errors. If somebody could help. I am using control_utils.js, camera_utils.js, control_utils_3d.js, pose.js, drawing_utils.js